# Python Coding difficulty arising with while and if loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am new to python coding and i need help with a question ,i am not able to understand where i am doing wrong, can you all please help me with it. If you help me understand this would quite helpful for me.

Question is that i need to return the grades of 2 students by their average score, problem is that the custom input is provided in such a way that it forms a nested list of the scores of the two students and the stub is written in such a way i am not able to change, please help me with this and i provide the provided stub for Better reference.

For the hands-on if statement of grading the students, i am using this code:

```
def calculateGrade(students_marks):
    avg = sum(students_marks)/5
    if avg >= 90:
        return 'A+'
    elif avg in range(80,90):
        return 'A'
    elif avg in range(70,80):
        return 'B'
    elif avg in range(60,70):
        return 'C'
    elif avg in range(50,60):
        return 'D'
    elif avg < 50:
        return 'F'
```

Provided stub:

```
if __name__ ='__main__':
fptr = open(os.environ["OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

 students_marks_rows = int(input().strip())
 students_marks_columns = int(input().strip())
 students_marks = [ ]
 for in range(students_marks_rows) :
    studentsmarks.append(list(map(int,input().rstrip().split())))
    result = calculateGrade(students_marks)
 fptr.write('\n'.join(result) )
 fptr.write('\n')
 fptr.close()
```

Comment: Please do not add (possibly only temporary) dropbox links. Rather edit the question to contain the question directly. Also please note that stackoverflow is not code-on-demand service. Do you have any problems with the provided code? What problem?

Comment: What is your second code problem?

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @Mehdi_Mostafavi the problem is that the provided custom input is in two rows which is stored in a variable as a nested listed, for example Sum = [[60,20,2,30,56],[30,24,40,5,11], now i do not understand how to bring out the average of both these list and return the grades for both the average calculated as A,B or C.

Answer (score 1):

you could take the sum of each list by accessing each one:
you can access nested lists just like lst[0], this will give you [60,20,2,30,56] then you can make a quick sum by using an already builtin function called sum().

so you would end up like this sum(lst[0]) => 168
and then you could also calculate the length of the list you accessed, like len(lst[0]), and then just divide the total amount by the length

Here I leave you a piece of code so you can analyse it.

```
lists = [[60,20,2,30,56],[30,24,40,5,11]]
for grade_list in lists:
    total = sum(grade_list)
    average = len(grade_list)
    result = total/average
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def calculateGrade(students_marks):
Gra=[]
for grade_list in students_marks:
    total=sum(grade_list)
    av=float(total/(len(grade_list)))
    if av >=90:
        Grades='A+'
    elif av >=80 and av <90:
         Grades='A'
    elif av >=70 and av <90:
         Grades='B'
    elif av >=60 and av <90:
         Grades='C'
    elif av >=50 and av <90:
         Grades='D'
    elif av <50:
         Grades='F'
    Gra.append(Grade)
return(Gra)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
def calculateGrade(students_marks):
    Gra = []
    for i in range(len(students_marks)):
        for j in range(len(students_marks[i])):
            total = sum(students_marks[i])
            av = float(total/len(students_marks[i]))
            if av >=90:
                Grades='A+'
            elif av >=80 and av <90:
                Grades='A'
            elif av >=70 and av <90:
                 Grades='B'
            elif av >=60 and av <90:
                 Grades='C'
            elif av >=50 and av <90:
                 Grades='D'
            elif av <50:
                Grades='F'
        Gra.append(Grades)
    return(Gra)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculateGrade(students_marks):  
    # Write your code here  
    list1 = list()  
    for i in range(len(students_marks)):  
        count = 0  
        sum = 0  
        avg = 0  
        for j in range(len(students_marks[i])):  
            count = count + 1  
            sum = sum + students_marks[i][j]  
        avg = sum/count  
        if avg >= 90:  
            list1.append("A+")  
        elif avg >= 80:  
            list1.append("A")  
        elif avg >= 70:  
            list1.append("B")  
        elif avg >= 60:  
            list1.append("C")  
        elif avg >= 50:  
            list1.append("D")  
        elif avg < 50:  
            list1.append("F")  
    return list1
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't help the original author spot where the problem lies in their solution. When writing answers, consider adding where the problem was, how it was fixed and why this way. Additionally, consider formatting your code, to increase readability. You can use the code block to automatically format and highlight the syntax.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Gra=[]

 for grade_list in students_marks:       
     total = sum(grade_list)
     number = len(grade_list)        
     av = total/number
    
     if av >=90:
        Grades='A+'
     elif av >=80 and av <90:
        Grades='A'
     elif av >=70 and av <90:
        Grades='B'
     elif av >=60 and av <90:
        Grades='C'
     elif av >=50 and av <90:
        Grades='D'
     elif av <50:
        Grades='F'
     Gra.append(Grades)
 for i in Gra:
    print(i)

 return(Gra)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).